# Flutter geolocator package not giving location in English

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am using Flutter geolocator package latest version and it gives location and names of country in English for most of the countries but for some countries like Germany, Spain, France, etc.. it's not giving names in English rather the native language of the user. How can I change this?

```
Position position = await geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
    desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.medium);

List<Placemark> placemark =
    await geolocator.placemarkFromCoordinates(
        position.latitude, position.longitude);
_location = {
  'country': placemark[0].country,
  'postalCode': placemark[0].postalCode,
  'state': placemark[0].administrativeArea,
  'city': placemark[0].subAdministrativeArea,
  'latitude': placemark[0].position.latitude,
  'longitude': placemark[0].position.latitude
};
_city = placemark[0].subAdministrativeArea;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Both the placemarkFromAddress and placemarkFromCoordinates accept an optional localeIdentifier parameter. This parameter can be used to enforce the resulting placemark to be formatted (and translated) according to the specified locale. The localeIdentifier should be formatted using the syntax: [languageCode]_[countryCode]. Use the ISO 639-1 or ISO 639-2 standard for the language code and the 2 letter ISO 3166-1 standard for the country code.

Meaning:

```dart
List<Placemark> placemark =
    await geolocator.placemarkFromCoordinates(
        position.latitude, position.longitude);
```

Should be:

```dart
List<Placemark> placemark =
    await geolocator.placemarkFromCoordinates(
        position.latitude, position.longitude, localeIdentifier: localeIdentifierValue);
```

https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator for more information on the options for localeIdentifierValue

Comment: So what should be the `localeIdentifierValue` for the English language so that place automatically gets converted to English?.

Comment: It's mentioned in the package -> en

Answer (score 0):

Placemark has been separated from the geolacator library and currently it is located in the gecoding library

make sure you get their respective libraries from pub.dev

```
import 'package:geocoding/geocoding.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    List<Placemark> placemark =
        await placemarkFromCoordinates(position.latitude, position.longitude);
```